# CUDAQ[] returns False in version 9 while True in version 8

Tags: cudalink

CUDA works in version 8 but not in version 9. Is there a way to fix the problem in version 9? I've installed the latest CUDA from the official website https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you might have to force reinstall it... I had a similar issue when v9 first came out (I don't exactly recall what I did)

Comment: This has happened to me.  Try this in v9: `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]; CUDAResourcesInstall[]`.  The download will take some time.

Comment: @Szabolcs it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may happen because the CUDA resources downloaded are for version 8 and are not compatible with version 9.  The problem can be fixed by re-installing them.  To do this, evaluate the following in version 9:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]

CUDAResourcesUninstall[]
CUDAResourcesInstall[]
```

The download is rather large, so it might take a while.